# Jquery validate (active/inactive)

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jquery validate plugin to control a form.

My question is how can I activate or deactivate the validate plugin through a checkbox or radio buttons?
The form in default mode is controlled by the plugin, and the user has an option to deactivate the form control.

Thanks again for sharing your knowledge!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you all the information you need: [Form Validator](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/validator/index.html)

But you could make something similar to :

```
$('#checkBox').change(function() {
    if ($('#checkBox').attr('checked')) {
        var validator = $("#myform").validator();
        validator.destroy();
    }
    else
         $("#myform").validator();
});
```